# How to show data from Database to in Django Templates

Tags: python, django

**I am learning django. My `views.py` is like below which is inside `student` app folder.**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from .models import Student
from student.models import Student


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    student_data = Student.objects.all()
    context = {
        'student_data': student_data
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context )
```

I am trying to get values in `index.html` template which is inside `template` folder. My code in `index.html` is like below.

```
<p>
  {{ student_data }}
</p>
```

My code of `models.py` which is inside `student` app is like below.

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    last_name=models.CharField( max_length=100, blank=True, null=True )
    age=models.IntegerField()
```

But I can't see any Data in HTML using browser.

Comment: Did you create students objects using admin?

Comment: Add Students objects to db using admin or consol and then try.

Comment: Thanks @Pycm. Yes, I created students objects using Admin. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFtsl.png

Comment: Then. Use this. `{% for student in student _data %}{{ student .first_name }}<br>{% endfor %}`. Make sure model have a str method. Witch will give you unique look in admin.

Comment: `{% for student in student _data %}{{ student.first_name }}<br>{% endfor %}`

Comment: What happened friend? Did you get it to work?

Comment: Thanks @Pycm. Actually I didn't add `<!DOCTYPE html>`. That's why I was not getting any output.